# Use variable data from a model's function on the controller where I called the function

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

So I have a website where I buy items. I do an if to see if the session data "moedas" (user's coins) is greater than or equal to the item's price. I want to get the item's data from my model where I have the model's function `dados_acessorio`. So I call this function on my controller and what I want is to receive that data and be able to use it on the same controller after. The problem is I am getting an error. I am new to php/CodeIgniter and I could use some help.

Here is the controller's function:

```
public function confirmarCompra($id){

     $this->load->model('acessorios_model','acessorios');
     $dados['acessorio'] = $this->acessorios->dados_acessorio($id)[0];

     if($this->session->moedas >= $acessorio['preco']){


     }
}
```

Here is the model's function:

```
public function dados_acessorio($id){

            return $this->db->from('acessorios')->where('id_acessorio', $id)->get()->result_array();
}
```

Here is an image of my `acessorios` table:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMOYB.jpg

The error that I receive on the controller:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoxdE.jpg

The error is on the following line:
`if($this->session->moedas >= $acessorio['preco'])`

Thanks!

Comment: looks like it could be a typo? `$acessorio` doesn't exist. Did you mean `if($this->session->moedas >= $dados['acessorio']['preco'])`?

Comment: @AntonyThompson Oh. I need to do $dados['acessorio']['preco'] ? When I am passing the data to the views ['acessorio'] becomes the variable. It worked now, thanks a lot. Should I delete this post?

Comment: That's good. No leave the post. It might help someone else who had the same problem.

Comment: I made an answer so you can you please accept this? It will mean the question is resolved. I noticed someone else added an answer and deleted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it could be a typo? `$acessorio` is how it will appear in the view.

change this:

```
if($this->session->moedas >= $acessorio['preco']){
```

to this

```
if($this->session->moedas >= $dados['acessorio']['preco']){
```